# haskell parsing contextfree-grammar to compare with a string

Tags: parsing, haskell, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to represent a context-free grammar which I would like to parse for comparing a String with the `"A"` of `Prod "A" [NT "B", NT "C"]`, but I don't know how, could someone please help me?

```
data Symbol a b = T a | NT b 
deriving (Eq,Show)

data Produktion a b = Prod b [Symbol a b]
deriving (Eq,Show)

type Produktionen a b = [Produktion a b]   

liste11 = [Prod "A" [NT "B", NT "C"]
      ,Prod "B" [NT "D", NT "E"]
      ,Prod "D" [T "d"]
      ] --
```

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht. What are you comparing? Are you comparing productions to each othet, or simply looking up a production by its name, such as "A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are easier ways but a primitive approach can be

```
fromNT :: (Symbol a b) -> b
fromNT (NT b) = b
fromNT (T a) = undefined

extractNT :: (Eq b) => b -> [Produktion a b] -> [[b]]   
extractNT _ [] = [[]]
extractNT b (p:ps)  | is p = (map fromNT (symbol p)) : extractNT b ps
                    | otherwise = []          
                    where is (Prod x xs) = x==b
                          symbol (Prod _ xs) = xs
```

now you can write

```
> extractNT "A" liste11                         
[["B","C"]]
```

**UPDATE**

I don't think it will work for generic types but for String String

```
value :: (Symbol String String) -> String
value (T a) = a
value (NT b) = b
```

the other accessors can still be generic

```
symbol :: (Produktion a b) -> [Symbol a b]
symbol (Prod _ ss) = ss

tag :: (Produktion a b) -> b
tag (Prod b _) = b
```

you can now say

```
> map (map value) $ map symbol $ filter (\p -> tag p=="D") liste11
[["d"]]

> map (map value) $ map symbol $ filter (\p -> tag p=="A") liste11
[["B","C"]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I need to extract the Terminals too, I have tried but couldnt solve ...

Comment: please update the question of what you want to extract.  The example you provided was exactly this case.

Comment: I edited productions list, Edit: I also want to extract the production "D" so it will be return the right side "d"

Comment: the results may not be homogeneous, what happens when you have a mix of T and NT cons?  You can get a list of `a` and `b` types.

Comment: the grammar shall be in Chomsky normal form, that means only NT to NT NT, or NT to T